# Keep showing the post after casting the final spam flag while reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, spam

When casting the final spam flag from the First Questions/First Answers/Late Answers queue, the post disappears and 'question/answer not found' is shown instead:

> [image]

This makes it difficult for example to go to the spammer's profile to see if more posts need flagging. (Note that the user information above the post is the author of the question, not the spammer.)

There is a workaround: after completing the review and navigating back, the question is shown again:

> [image]

But it would be easier if it is shown (with a red background, of course) while still reviewing.

Comment: Also, does someone want to explain why you can select "Looks OK" after you've just cast the last spam flag?

Comment: @Laurel Because that interface is not tightly coupled to the state of the post. It doesn't detect whether you took some other action that would finish the review. It would be very frustrating if I flagged something for mod attention for reasons unrelated to the post quality and then couldn't say "Looks OK". If it doesn't look OK, I think we can trust that you won't click that :)